# C# : what regular expression can match these text?

Tags: c#, regex

what regular expression can match these in C#:

```
^TEST(%USER,"ADDRESS","NAME","^\",()")
^TEST(%USER,"ADDRESS","NAME")
^TEST()
^TEST
^TEST("HALLO")
$$TEST^QCC("HALLO")
$$TEST^QCC
```

I hope i can get two groups:

group 1: the text before left round bracket if there is a left round bracket, otherwise the whole text.

group 2: the text between the round bracket.

I tried regular expression "(\S+)((\S+))" at https://regex101.com/r/R5wiOh/12 but it works not good.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Can there be something after `^TEST(...)` ?

Comment: And is `^TEST` static text?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/8

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/9)

Comment: @JvdV hi, your regular expression works good for me. but i have more text to match. see the modification. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(\S+?)(?:\((\S*)\))?$
```

It is basically the same regex you used, but makes an optional non capturing group around the second group. This means: If it's available capture its content into group 2.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

^(\S+?)((\S*))$